# Unable to activate MATLAB

Tags: 12.10, matlab

I have a Problem with the Matlab (2012a Student Version) Activation. The following message pops up when I try to activate:

```
Error 1,714: Unable to activate your machine. The activation process cannot detect a valid Host ID which utilizes the 'eth' naming
convention. Please refer to the following solution ID, to help resolve
this issue: 1-661QJD
```

I refered to the solution ID on the mathworks [page](http://www.mathworks.ch/support/solutions/en/data/1-661QJD/index.html?solution=1-661QJD). Their way to solve the problem is to rename the `eth` device in the `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` file by doing the following:

> Simply replace the name in the NAME= field to be eth0 and reboot the
>   machine. Once rebooted, the machine should now have an eth0 device.

The problem is, that the device in my *persistent net rules file* is already called `eth0`.

I have a Dell XPS netbook (and Ubuntu 12.10 on it) which has only wifi (I read somewhere that netbooks dont have an ethN device, which I guess is part of the problem).

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to your `/etc/udev/rules.d/`
2. Edit your `.rules` file and change `Name="wlan0"` to `Name="eth0"` and temporarily name your `eth0` to `eth1`
3. Restart your machine and fire up the activation script.

This should work. You can revert back to the original names after you activate Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing:

```
# ln -s /dev/null /etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-name-slot.rules
```

Reboot and fire up the activation script! You will get the unpredictable interface naming convention again, though.

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can retrieve a license file for activation in case of not having root user authority, for instance, to change system files under `/etc` directory tree.

1. Log into your MathWorks Account at https://www.mathworks.com/login
2. Go to the License Center:
   https://www.mathworks.com/licensecenter/licenses
3. Select your license number from the list. If you don't see your
   license, use the links in the upper left hand corner to toggle
   between Licenses, Trials, and Prereleases
4. Select the "Install and Activate" tab
5. If you don't see a list of activations on this page, click the
   "Activate to Retrieve License File" link under "Related Tasks" on
   the right side of the page.
6. Follow the instruction to obtain a license file.
7. Go ahead to Matlab "Activation". Choose "Activate manually without
   the internet" and then "Provide the path to the license file" with the path of the license file you obtained in #6.

Reference:

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/235126-how-do-i-generate-a-matlab-license-file

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101892-what-is-a-host-id-how-do-i-find-my-host-id-in-order-to-activate-my-license?s_tid=srchtitle